# ArrayList .contains() not working

Tags: java, android, arraylist, equals, hashcode

I have this array of messages and I want to update it with new messages that I get from a API call. I'm iterating through the array I get and then I check if the messages are already in ArrayList or not. If not, I add it to the list.

But, for some unknown reason, it's not working. It's duplicating all the items in the list, but the new item is never there. I can't figure out what's wrong with my `equals()` or `hashCode()` implementation.

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        boolean result = false;
        if (object == null || object.getClass() != getClass()) {
            result = false;
        } else {
            Message mess = (Message) object;
            if (this.id == mess.getId() && this.extid == mess.getExtid()) {
                result = true;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 7 * hash + this.id.hashCode();
        hash = 7 * hash + this.extid.hashCode();
        return hash;
    }
```

`populateData()`:

```
    private void populateData(String response) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray ArrayMessages = jsonObject.getJSONArray("messages");

            Gson gson = new Gson();

            Message[] messages = gson.fromJson(ArrayMessages.toString(), Message[].class);

            for (Message message : messages) {
                if(!messageList.contains(message)) {
                    messageList.add(message);
                }
            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: What is the type of `id` and `extid`?  Since you're running `hashCode()` on them, I bet they aren't primitives, in which case trying to compare them with `==` isn't going to work like you think it is...

Comment: You can use HashSet insteadof List in this case.

Comment: What is adapter here?

Comment: Your hash is not combining id and extid. extid is overwriting what you did with id. Was it supposed to be a `+=`?

Comment: `id` and `extid` are Strings, I can't believe I didn't think about that! Using `equals()` solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

What type are `id` and `extId`? You should be comparing them with `equals()` instead of `==` and using a `set` would avoid having to check if the element is already in the collection because sets don't allow duplicates.